Why don't move the dataset file pointer to the header when training the fashion-mnist dataset after each epoch?
I'm implementing an Artificial Neural Network (ANN) in C++ using fashion-mnist dataset based on this source code. I, however, confuse about the way reading the mnist training files.
This is the training code:
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
using namespace std;

ifstream image;
ifstream label;

double input[784];
double expected[10];

void next_sample()
{
  char number;

  //read the next image
  for (int i = 0; i < 28; i++){
    for (int j = 0;j < 28; j++){
      image.read(&number, sizeof(char));
      input[i * 28 + j]=number / 255.0;
    }
  }

  //read the next label
  label.read(&number, sizeof(char));
  for (int i = 0; i < 10; ++i) {
    expected[i] = 0.0;
  }
  expected[number] = 1.0;
}


int main()
{
  image.open("train-images-idx3-ubyte", ios::in | ios::binary); // Binary image file
  label.open("train-labels-idx1-ubyte", ios::in | ios::binary ); // Binary label file

  char number;
  for (int i = 0; i < 16; i++) { //read the header in the image file
    image.read(&number, sizeof(char));
  }
  
  for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++) { //read the header in the label file
    label.read(&number, sizeof(char));
  }


  for (int e = 0;e < 5;e++){
    for (int sample = 1; sample <= 60000; ++sample) {            
      // Getting (image, label)
      next_sample();
            
      // Learning process: Perceptron (Forward procedure) - Back propagation
      int nIterations = learning_process();
    }
  }
}

The mnist dataset files containing 60000 images and labels, aka samples, were opened to provide data for training process.
next_sample() function is to take the next image and label for learning process. It transforms a 28x28 two-dimension image to a 784-length array. Then, it read the next corresponding label.
I would like to train all 60000 samples in 5 times by 2 nested loops. In the inner loop, next_sample() is to take the next training sample from the dataset files, learning_process() then executes both forward and backward propagation for updating the weights and biases on layers in the ANN. When the inner loop ends, I think all samples are read and we are at the end of file (EOF), but the next loops occurs without any errors. That means the program continues to read the dataset files, despite EOF, without moving the file pointer to the head by
image.seekg(0, std::ios::beg);
label.seekg(0, std::ios::beg);

My confusion is that after the inner loop ends why the author doesn't move the file pointer of the dataset files to the beginning to the next training because we reached to EOF. Whether it is a bug and should I move the file pointer to the head by seekg() function?

Side note: Why would you mix std::cout AND printf in the same code base? Have a look at std::format (C++20) and std::print (C++23) instead.

More on topic the code you show doesn't do anything with files at all. So how can we know? IThe question also lacks any debug information on what actually goes wrong. And we are not going to follow links to external resources, your question must be self-contained. So your question needs a lot of updating.

@PepijnKramer I've just edited the post. Please give me your comment if it still is not enough to be a good question!

Is the post clearer, so it no longer gets down votes?
